# responsive navigation getting jumpy with display flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, flexbox

so, I tried to remaster my previous projects and change it into flex. and it getting messed up because of `ul` element is block and I changed it using JavaScript into a display flex.

this is the fiddle

```js
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('#pull');
        menu        = $('nav ul.clearfix');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();
 
    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  $('#burger').toggleClass('open');
  if ($('#burger').hasClass("open")) {
   $(menu).css("display", "flex");
   $("section").css("z-index", 1);
   menu.slideToggle();
  } else {
   menu.slideToggle('slow', function() {
   $("section").css("z-index", 4);
   });
  }
    });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

```css
header{
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}
header #logo{
width:15%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:2;
}
#logo img{
width:100%;
}
header nav{
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
nav ul.clearfix{
width:100%;
padding:0;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
ul.clearfix a{
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none;
border:solid 2px #e74c3c;
padding:8px 0px;
width:12%;
max-width:300px;
font-size:15px;
color:#e74c3c;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
ul.clearfix a:nth-child(n+2){
margin-left:-1px;
}
ul.clearfix a:hover{
padding:16px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#e74c3c;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul.clearfix #currentPage{
padding:16px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#e74c3c;
cursor:pointer; 
}

/*default*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
header{
 height:50px;
 justify-content:flex-start;
}
nav {
 z-index:2;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 border-bottom: 0; 
 }
nav a#pull{
 line-height:50px;}
nav ul.clearfix {
 width:100%;
 display: none;
 height: auto;
 background:#ccc;
 position:relative;
 flex-direction:column;
 z-index:2;
}
ul.clearfix a{
 border-bottom:1px dotted black;
 font-size:14px;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:2;
}
ul.clearfix a:first-child{
 border-top:1px dotted black;  
 margin-top:50px;
}
nav a#pull {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 align-items:flex-start;
 justify-content:flex-start;
 padding-left:10px;
 right:10px;
 top:5px;
}
nav a#pull:after {
 background:#ccc;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 line-height:50px;
 right:15px;
 top:0px;}

div#burger{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 position: absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index:4;}
div#burger span{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 border-radius: 9px;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
 transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
 }
#burger span:nth-child(1){top: 0px;}
#burger span:nth-child(2){top: 7px;}
#burger span:nth-child(3){top: 14px;} 

#burger.open span:nth-child(1){
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#burger.open span:nth-child(2){
  opacity: 0;
  left: -30px;
}

#burger.open span:nth-child(3){
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}


}

/*default Portrait*/
@media screen and (max-width: 773px) and (orientation: portrait) {
div#logo{
 width:30%;
}

}
/* iPad Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

div#logo{
 width:20%;}
   
}

/* iPad Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
header{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
}
div#logo {
width: 25%;}
nav {
width: 65%;}
}

/*default Landscape*/
@media screen and (max-width: 773px) and (orientation: landscape) {
div#logo{
 width:20%;
} 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <header class="sameThisHeight">
  <div id="logo" class="logo">
   <img src="assets/Logo.png">
  </div>
  <nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
   <a id="currentPage" href="index.php">HOME</a>
   <a href="registration.php">REGISTRATION</a>
   <a href="tutorial.php">TUTORIAL</a>
   <a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="pull">
   <div id="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </div>
    </a>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

The thing is,

when i tried to clicked the burger at the first time it's back and forth like it has something wrong with it.

and the second time i opened the burger, it collapse the nav and it did good, no no it's not good actually it's not good at all.

Somehow the sequence has changed the "x" button for the opening the nav and the "burger icon" to close the nav. It definetly not ok.

I don't know for what i did so wrong about it, the right thing should be in place is the opposite of what i did the "x" button for close the nav and the "burger icon" to open up the nav.

My thought was because I inserted this in my JavaScript

> ```
> $(menu).css("display", "flex");
> ```

Because, before i adding this into my javascript it did good performance but not good enough to match with the design. the last project i did fine because of not using flex and go stright with UL LI tags. is there anyway to solve this problem, and keep using flex for it? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines causes the issue on first time clicking. You should put the `display: flex` after the `slideToggle();`, I should point out that it will not be a smooth transition as the `slideToggle();` puts the `display: block;`. You should maybe do a css solution or maybe make a container around the `<ul>...</ul>`.

```
if ($('#burger').hasClass("open")) {
  //here you set it to be display
  $(menu).css("display", "flex");

  $("section").css("z-index", 1);

  //here you toggle display, which will be flex, so you hide it
  menu.slideToggle(); 
}
```

change to ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8zcL1jj/2/), I changed your styling a bit for demo, you are free to use your own)

```
$(function() {
  var pull = $('#pull');
  menu = $('nav ul.clearfix');
  menuHeight = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#burger').toggleClass('open');
    if ($('#burger').hasClass("open")) {
      $("section").css("z-index", 1);
      menu.slideToggle();
    } else {
      menu.slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $("section").css("z-index", 4);
      });
    }
  });
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  var w = $(window).width();
  if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

Your html/css has some issues and should be re-worked.
The `<ul>` has to contain `<li>`

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <a id="currentPage" href="index.php">HOME</a>
  <a href="registration.php">REGISTRATION</a>
  <a href="tutorial.php">TUTORIAL</a>
  <a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a>
</ul>
```

should be

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li><a id="currentPage" href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="registration.php">REGISTRATION</a></li>
  <li><a href="tutorial.php">TUTORIAL</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also why do you use the class `clearfix` when you are not using float? I never target a `clearfix` class for styling as you do in this case, rather give it a class of `navigation` or something.

Comment: thx for your concern @dejan it is what i really wanted, so we can't change that slideToggle into display flex?? it's a bit  longer if we put another wrap for ul tags, and i think your li tags does not necessary.

Comment: and one more thing @dejan, about ul class clearfix, does this class name could change something? what i'm saying is, it just a class name and the property inside the classes it self is what we really wanted to type no? or a "clearfix class" has an independent property without i'm knowing.

Comment: @Obink No, `slideToggle()` sets element into `display: block;` and there is no way to change that at this moment.

Comment: @Obink `clearfix` is not something out of the "box" but that classname is kinda reserved used/refered to clearing floats in html, so it's not that good practice to use that for other reasons then just "clearfix". I mean you are free to use it but if you more devs are working on it now, or if it's gone be passed to others, I woulden't use it. It's also for your own learning :)